# IIS and Apache on the same machine and same port for a real deployment (non testing server)

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, deployment

I'm trying to run both IIS and Apache on the same machine and on the same port: I read this interesting post and it's working very well, but only for a local access (it doesn't work for a remote access):

www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=559060

So it's very useful for local testing, but unuseful for a real world deployment.
Any chance to make it work also from a remote access? (I mean, i.e, using a No-IP address like http://mysite.no-ip.org/ instead of local http://mysite/)

I read other articles and I know I can run PHP on IIS, but I'd like to have both servers since I can run ASP sites on IIS and make mod_rewrite on Apache
So, can it be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Apache's `mod_proxy` and creating a separate virtual host in Apache to proxy all requests going to that virtual host to IIS.